# What would be my best option for creating a relationship between tables when the data from both tables will be used often?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm completely redesigning my company's databases, back-end and front-end. One thing I've seen discussed online quite often is defining the relationships between tables using a primary key, clustered indexes, non-clustered indexes, etc.

In terms of performance, I've been debating how to best setup the structure for a couple of my tables. Within several of the tables, there is a location field. In the current setup, users manually enter the location, something similar to C1.H39.3. Where C1 denotes the building, .H is the letter, 39 is the number, and .3 is the tile.

My question is how should I link my location table to my other tables. The location table is setup with ID (identity), building, letter, number, and tile columns. When creating my relationships, would it be better to merely have a column for the id, or should I composite the columns together? What would be more beneficial to performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't store concatenated values in a single field.  You should split these out into what they actually represent and have 4 fields(Building, Letter, Number, Tile). This will save you headaches down the road.  If you want to show the exact location, you can display those values concatenated back together.

If you want to grab all the records in building C for example, this would be more difficult if the data is all in a single field.

Also, this has the added benefit of allowing you to create lookup tables.  You should have a table for bulidings, with the BuildingID, and building details, a table for Letters with all the letters etc.  One of the problems it sounds like you may face is that when users MANUALLY enter in this complex location human errors are more likely.  If you use a look up table the user will be less likely to make a mistake.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but would it be more beneficial to have the locations split and stored in all the tables that will be using them, or am I better off just including a foreign key to the locations table itself?

Comment: I would split it in all tables.  This is a fairly straight forward process if you are worried about re-defining your current data.  The bulk of the work would be in the front end, not the tables.  The benefit of doing this would be that you could grab all records in all tables that have a Tile of 6 for example.

Comment: What would the method of creating a relationship between the location table and the other table look like at that point?

Comment: I don't think I would have a location table.  How many records are in the locations table?

Comment: A little more than 90,000 and the location has to fall into one of them. The company I work for is an electrical contractor, and we're responsible for maintaining multiple massive data centers and their adjacent offices. Every location is recorded, and information regarding the devices within those locations are recorder. The location table itself merely contains all the different locations.

Comment: I'm rather inexperienced with SQL programming, but if my thinking is correct, if I wanted to sort by, let's say building C1, letter .D, could I not simply join the locations table on the other tables where the IDs match, and sort the resulting recordset? The previous developer merely had a location field, with the full location path for every component. For validation purposes, I think we'll have to have a location table.

Comment: You could do that easily if the (Building, Letter, Number, Tile) were in separate fields. If they are in a single field, you would need to parse the string to do sorting on parts of the string.

Comment: I dont really see a need for a locations table,  So you want to find all the info about building C Letter D.  You could just grab all the records that have building C and letter D, I dont know why you would have a location table.

Comment: Well my mentality is I need to validate that the location actually exists, and having a table that contains every single location prevents accidentally mistyping the location, and also allows me to create a predictive field for the end user.

Comment: that is why I would have a table for each piece of info.  Eg a Buildings Table.  This would allow a building to store more information, maybe the address, the manager, the alarm code etc.  Then  when you are putting the info into other tables, you put in the buildingID in a single field.  The same thing would be true for Letter, Number and Tile.

Comment: The issue is, for our purposes, we only need the location information, nothing more. That's why it isn't really expanded much further.